# Permanently show the legend on a graph

Tags: legend, qliksense

i basically have a problem with my Qlik sense i cant seem to display the legends for one of the graph due to its being small.

is there a way to display the legend permanetly without it being moved around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so, one of the trade offs with Qlik Sense is that for the dynamic resizing to each screen is that controls over appearance are not as stringent.